# Add elements incrementally to a Variable

Tags: prolog

So, I have this code:

```
classif_operacoes(op1,opt1).
classif_operacoes(op2,opt2).

op_to_opt([],[_]).
op_to_opt([H|T],[V|Lf]):-
                        classif_operacoes(H,Li),
                        V is Li,
                        op_to_opt(T,Lf).
```

What iwant to happen is I call:

```
 op_to_opt([op1,op2],L).
```

and get this:

```
L=[opt1,opt2];
```

This sample code doens't work for me.

The first clause basically transforms my H into another value, that I want to store into my variable Lf, which is a list. I want to iterate through the first list, and add the result of the first clause to the result.

I want Lf to be a list.

Sorry is this is basic, but couldn't come up with an answer.

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you aim to do. The first clause would mean that you "transform" an empty list into a singleton list with a variable.

Comment: Can you reformulate your question and perhaps add some sample data?

Comment: what I'm missing is how I recursevely add values to my Lf variable.

Comment: You can use `op_to_opt([H|T], [V|Lf]) :-...`. Then you set the value `V` and `Lf` is the "tail" and thus a list of remaining lists that you then (likely) fill in with recursion.

Comment: I edited my question, hoping it makes it more comprehensive!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [**`is/2`** predicate [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(is)/2) is used to evaluate a *numerical* expression at the right operand, and unify this with the left operand. But since you use constants (like `op1` and `op2`) that will not work.

You however do not need to evaluate anything. You can simply unify `V` with the result, like:

```
op_to_opt([],[]).
op_to_opt([H1|T1],[H2|T2]):-
    classif_operacoes(H1,H2),
    op_to_opt(T1, T2).
```

or you can make use of [**`maplist/3`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3):

```
op_to_opt(LA, LB) :-
    maplist(classif_operacoes, LA, LB).
```

Comment: This works, but i get this list: L = [opt1, opt2, opt1, opt2, opt1|_6852]. and I don't understand why I'm getting those numbers.

Comment: @TiagoPires: did you rewrite the second parameter of the first clause to `[]`?